# ReactJS CoreUI - How to use URL path param in Sidebar Item

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

I am newbie in developing an application using React JS and Core UI template.

I want to make 2 different page and different Sidebar for each page.

- Page 1: Data
- Sidebar Menu: Datas

In Data page layout, the data from database will show in a DataTable, and each row will have button 'Artifact'. Everytime the button is clicked, it will push to page Artifact

```
history.push(`/datas/${idData}/artifacts/}`
```

- Page 2: Artifact
- Sidebar Menu: Datas, Artifacts

I am using Core UI template with _navArtifact.js to store the Sidebar item when Artifact page is showing.

This is the _navArtifact.js
import React from 'react'

```
const _navArtifact =  [
  {
    _tag: 'CSidebarNavItem',
    name: 'Datas',
    to: '/datas'
  },
  {
    _tag: 'CSidebarNavItem',
    name: 'Artifact',
    to: '/datas/:id/artifact'
  }
]

export default _navArtifact
```

And this is the ArtifactSidebar.js that will create component for Sidebar item

```
import navigation from './_navArtifact'

const ArtifactSidebar = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()   
  
  return (
    <CSidebar
      show={show}
      onShowChange={(val) => dispatch({type: 'set', sidebarShow: val })} >
      
      <CSidebarNav>
        <CCreateElement
          items={navigation}
          components={{
            CSidebarNavDivider,
            CSidebarNavDropdown,
            CSidebarNavItem,
            CSidebarNavTitle
          }}
        />
      </CSidebarNav>
    </CSidebar>
  )
}

export default React.memo(ArtifactSidebar)
```

Now my problem is the Sidebar item 'Artifact' is link to '/datas/:id/artifact'.
How to use param :id in the _navArtifact.js?

Current URL: `localhost:3000/#/datas/123456/artifact/datas/:id/artifact`

Expected: `localhost:3000/#/datas/123456/artifact`

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @Dwidi, did you get any solution for this? I am facing the same issue.